# Getting exception of node pool when trying to run [acm-terraform-blog-part1]

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

> Error: error creating NodePool: googleapi: Error 400: Creation of node
> pools using node images based on Docker container runtimes is not
> supported in GKE v1.23. This is to prepare for the removal of
> Dockershim in Kubernetes v1.24. We recommend that you migrate to image
> types based on Containerd (examples). For more information, contact
> Cloud Support., badRequest.

what could be the fix for this?

Comment: you can share the terraform code and variables that you are passing so get some idea feel free to update question with details.

Comment: Assuming you cloned https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine, you'll need to update the "version" field for the GKE module to "19.0" or later.  You can find the field here:  https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/blob/master/examples/acm-terraform-blog-part1/terraform/gke.tf#L34

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you cloned github.com/terraform-google-modules/…, you'll need to update the "version" field for the GKE module to "19.0" or later. You can find the field here:

https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-kubernetes-engine/blob/master/examples/acm-terraform-blog-part1/terraform/gke.tf#L34

Comment: And if not? What then? I installed terraform via brew install.

Comment: I am still getting error and i am using following code 
https://github.com/kusznerr/sample-gke-terraform/blob/main/main.tf#L44